# Vercel: Command "npm run build" exited with 1

Tags: next.js, vercel

I'm relatively unfamiliar with deployment, Next.js and also Vercel. I am currently experiencing two fatal errors when building.

```
[22:35:25.855] Running build in Cleveland, USA (East) – cle1
[22:35:25.912] Cloning github.com/REDACTED/website (Branch: main, Commit: e8b813a)
[22:35:45.575] Cloning completed: 19.663s
[22:35:45.688] Skipping build cache since Package Manager changed from "yarn" to "npm"
[22:35:45.709] Running "vercel build"
[22:35:46.152] Vercel CLI 28.17.0
[22:35:46.709] Running "install" command: `npm install`...
[22:35:53.514] 
[22:35:53.515] added 299 packages, and audited 300 packages in 7s
[22:35:53.515] 
[22:35:53.515] 109 packages are looking for funding
[22:35:53.515]   run `npm fund` for details
[22:35:53.516] 
[22:35:53.516] found 0 vulnerabilities
[22:35:53.832] 
[22:35:53.832] > tailwindui-salient@0.1.0 build
[22:35:53.832] > next build
[22:35:53.832] 
[22:35:54.242] warn  - You have enabled experimental feature (scrollRestoration) in next.config.js.
[22:35:54.243] warn  - Experimental features are not covered by semver, and may cause unexpected or broken application behavior. Use at your own risk.
[22:35:54.243] 
[22:35:54.268] Attention: Next.js now collects completely anonymous telemetry regarding usage.
[22:35:54.268] This information is used to shape Next.js' roadmap and prioritize features.
[22:35:54.268] You can learn more, including how to opt-out if you'd not like to participate in this anonymous program, by visiting the following URL:
[22:35:54.268] https://nextjs.org/telemetry
[22:35:54.268] 
[22:35:54.403] info  - Linting and checking validity of types...
[22:35:56.309] 
[22:35:56.310] Failed to compile.
[22:35:56.310] 
[22:35:56.310] ./src/components/Footer.jsx
[22:35:56.310] 12:11  Warning: Do not use `<img>` element. Use `<Image />` from `next/image` instead. See: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/no-img-element  @next/next/no-img-element
[22:35:56.310] 24:13  Warning: Do not use `<img>` element. Use `<Image />` from `next/image` instead. See: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/no-img-element  @next/next/no-img-element
[22:35:56.310] 
[22:35:56.310] ./src/components/Header.jsx
[22:35:56.310] 99:13  Warning: Do not use `<img>` element. Use `<Image />` from `next/image` instead. See: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/no-img-element  @next/next/no-img-element
[22:35:56.310] 
[22:35:56.310] ./src/components/Pricing.jsx
[22:35:56.311] 90:12  Error: `'` can be escaped with `&apos;`, `&lsquo;`, `&#39;`, `&rsquo;`.  react/no-unescaped-entities
[22:35:56.311] 
[22:35:56.311] info  - Need to disable some ESLint rules? Learn more here: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/eslint#disabling-rules
[22:35:56.336] Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 1
[22:35:56.717] BUILD_UTILS_SPAWN_1: Command "npm run build" exited with 1
```

The two fatal errors of course being:
`[22:35:56.336] Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 1 [22:35:56.717] BUILD_UTILS_SPAWN_1: Command "npm run build" exited with 1`, and:
`[22:35:56.310] Failed to compile.`

Really hoping for some help on this one as I'm completely stumped.

I've attempted reinstalling the node_modules several times, deploying several times and many other things..

I've attempted to switch the Build Command to `CI='' npm run build` and that changed nothing but the syntax in the error.

Answer (score 4):

run `npm run lint` and see where the error is coming from. You should fix the warnings too.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 3):

I am facing this issue from 3- 4 days now it fixed.
I face this issue because of .env file, there are many env variables I am using in my project.
The issue occurs because on next build next.js get error.

**solving approach**

1. I comment all code which **using env variables** and rename all file under **api/** folder and in components.
2. Keep in mind that if you use any api inside api/ folder
   first deploy api and use that api in next commit

I hope it works for you. Thanks

Comment: Approach 2 worked for me. Thanx

Answer (score 1):

This helped to me:
Go to your `.esintrc.json` and chage content for:

```
{
  "extends": "next",
  "rules": {
    "react/no-unescaped-entities": "off",
    "@next/next/no-page-custom-font": "off"
  }
}
```

It was an error with eslint permissions deployment in vercel. Hope that could help you.

Answer (score 1):

It is because of ESLint
For **Next.js**
Open next.config.js and enable the ignoreDuringBuilds option in the eslint config:

module.exports = {
eslint: {
ignoreDuringBuilds: true
}
}

Answer (score 0):

You can see your specific bug causing this by entering on terminal `"npm run build"` locally. This should show you the bug that is causing your build to fail.

Comment: The problem is that locally, it builds nice, but not at Vercel

Answer (score 0):

Here are two ways to fix this error.

First run `npm run build` if you get an error like this `Error: Dynamic server usage: searchParams.userId` this is because you're using a dynamic server in your nextjs project. so on your `app/page.tsx` add this to the page `export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic'` read docs: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/route-segment-config#dynamic

Another fix is this: If you are getting a message like this in varcel while deploying: *Prisma has detected that this project was built on Vercel, which caches dependencies.
This leads to an outdated Prisma Client because Prisma's auto-generation isn't triggered.
To fix this, make sure to run the `prisma generate` command during the build process.
Learn how: https://pris.ly/d/vercel-build*

first: add this your package.json

```
{
  ...
  "scripts" {
    "postinstall": "prisma generate"
  }
```

then, add this to your build script:

```
"scripts" {
    "build": "prisma generate && <actual-build-command>"
  }
```

And remember to add this to the varcel build command: instead of `next build` add `npx prisma generate && next build`
read docs: https://www.prisma.io/docs/guides/other/troubleshooting-orm/help-articles/vercel-caching-issue

I hope this solves your issue, this was how I was able to solve mine after researching on the internet for hours.

Answer (score 0):

Literally this:

> 90:12  Error: `'` can be escaped with `&apos;`, `&lsquo;`, `&#39;`,
> `&rsquo;`.  react/no-unescaped-entities

Just use `&apos;` or whichever character you are using, rather than changing the ESLint rules for cleaner code.

Answer (score -1):

This is one way to fix that you can see if something of that is working for you

https://weekendprojects.dev/posts/resolved-npm-error-fix-the-upstream-dependency-conflict/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).